# How to disable or remove the Choose Picture & Remove Button in Edit Profile SharePoint 2010?

Tags: user-profile, user-experience

Is there a way to remove or disable the Choose Picture and Remove button in Edit Profile for Users?

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to central admin
2. Application Management -> Manage service applications
3. User Profile Service Application
4. People -> Manage User Properties
5. Picture -> Edit
6. Edit Settings -> Do not allow users to edit values for this property